# AspectJ pointcut && is behaving like ||

Tags: java, aspectj, aspect

I have the following advice:

```
@Before("execution(* com.myapp..*.*(..)) && !execution(* com.myapp.cms.workflow..*.*(..))")
public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    log.info("Calling " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
}
```

When I add the second condition to the pointcut:

```
&& !execution(* com.myapp.cms.workflow..*.*(..))
```

it logs every method call from every package.

I want the advice only to apply if its in the myapp package but not under the workflow package. Can anyone advise what I've done wrong?

AspectJ 1.6.8

Answer (score 0):

> it logs every method call from every package

No, it does not. It logs every method from package `com.myapp` and all its subpackages only, except for everything inside and below `com.myapp.cms.workflow`. If this is not what you want, maybe you should change your pointcut.

BTW, why are you using an outdated AspectJ version from 2009? It only supports Java 6 which is long out of support.

---

**Update:**

As you seem to not believe me, here is proof that your statement is wrong.

**Java classes according to your example:**

```java
package com.myapp;

public class Foo {
  public String convert(Integer number) {
    return number.toString();
  }
}
```

```java
package com.myapp.cms.workflow;

public class Workflow {
  public void doSomething() {}
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import com.myapp.Foo;
import com.myapp.cms.workflow.Workflow;

public class Application {
  // Should not be logged
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Should be logged
    new Foo().convert(11);
    // Should not be logged
    new Workflow().doSomething();
  }
}
```

**Aspect according to your example:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class LogAspect {
  @Before("execution(* com.myapp..*.*(..)) && !execution(* com.myapp.cms.workflow..*.*(..))")
  public void logBefore(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
      System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
  }
}
```

I compiled with Java 8 and AspectJ 1.8.13. I even tried from the console with AspectJ 1.6.8 and Java 1.6.0_45, the result is exactly the same.

**Console log:**

```
execution(String com.myapp.Foo.convert(Integer))
```

Ergo: Everything works as expected. Either you have not shown me your real pointcut or you forgot to remove another aspect logging everything from the classpath or whatever. AspectJ is not the problem. The problem sits in front of the computer, I would assume.

Comment: I want it to behave how you described but it's not working, it is currently logging every method from every package which is not what I want. My point-cut looks correct but its not working.